# (PaddleOCR) Error: "SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl-certificate, paddle-paddle

Attempting to run paddleocr throws the following error:

`[SSL:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)`

Python version 3.7

Operating System: MacOS 10.13

PaddleOCR  version 2.6.1.3

pip version:  10.0.1

Tried the following:

Reinstalling the ssl certificate via applications -> python 3.7 -> install certificates.command

Updating certifi via `pip3 install git+https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi -U`